# Angular 4 Confirm Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, jquery-confirm

I'm trying to create a directive for [jQuery Confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) in Angular 4. However, I'm having a hard time stopping binded events happening. Here is my structure:

**menus.component.html:**

```
<a (click)="delete(menu)" class="btn" confirm><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
```

**menus.component.ts:**

```
delete(menu: Menu): void {
    this.menuService.delete(menu.id)
        .subscribe(
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

**confirm.directive.ts:**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[confirm]' })
export class ConfirmDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        $(el.nativeElement).on('click', function () {
            $(this).confirm({
                confirm: function () {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Confirmation box does appear, but the event is fired before it, so it is useless. I want this directive to stop an event from firing, fire it if the action is confirmed, cancel it otherwise.

Comment: Why it's useless?

Comment: Because event is always fired whether I confirm or not.

Comment: OMG Angular 4 is released? What am doing :O :O Where is angular 3?

Comment: @RameshRajendran they have skipped 3. Also it is just "Angular" now, the current stable version is v4.0.0. In 6 months, it will be v5.0.0.

Comment: because  this.router.navigate(['/menus']); always gets executed after you init your modal. You should only navigate in your subscription result (after you click smt)

Comment: @Alexander it is something special to my model. Even if I remove that line, the Delete event still occurs. Our priority is to stop Delete event from happening, if user does not confirm.

Comment: @Alexander edited the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually combine directive name and output together.

```
 <button class="btn" (confirm)="delete()">delete</button>

 @Directive({
   selector: '[confirm]'
 }) 
 export class ConfirmDirective {
   @Output() confirm = new EventEmitter<any>();

   constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
   }

   @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
      $.confirm({
      buttons: {
     confirm: () => this.confirm.emit()
   }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: My problem is still not solved. delete() event in your code is not fired @Julia

Comment: can u create a plunker please, so i can see why it does not work?

Comment: I created a Plunker, but it works lol. https://plnkr.co/edit/J1GMyfGLx4bJ3e9hfXz3. I should re-debug my code then.

Comment: Good.Let me know how i can help you with it.

Comment: It turns out that whole problem was caused by my out-dated jQuery Confirm library. Your directive works very well, thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

I would work around it like this:

```
@Directive({ 
  selector: '[confirm]' 
})
export class ConfirmDirective {

  @Output('confirm-click') click: any = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) clicked(e) {
    $.confirm({
      buttons: {
        confirm: () => this.click.emit(),
        cancel: () => {}
      }
    });
  }

}
```

your html should look like:

```
<a (confirm-click)="delete(menu)" class="btn" confirm>Delete</a>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tAC6q4nLuA4tzx2X)**

Comment: Wow, nice solution!

Comment: Thanks for the help but we have a tiny problem. It doesn't run the function even if I use it like this:

    <a (confirm-click)="alert(1)" class="btn" confirm><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>

Comment: @yurzui I gave the example of alert(1) for just being simple. Something is missing in my code, I don't know what, but it does not let the code you suggested work.

Comment: Read about template variables scope in angular2. I added alert as property to component

Comment: Since my function is within a component, should I call it as (confirm-click)="menuService.delete(menu)" or something?

Comment: It turns out that whole problem was caused by my out-dated jQuery Confirm library. Your directive works very well, thanks again.

Comment: All those plunkers do not longer work. no wonder the world have moved on from it

Comment: @Eris Sorry for that. Updated  https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tAC6q4nLuA4tzx2X